# Append and then insert an element in array in the same program

Tags: arrays, c

I want to append and then insert an element in an array. Append() function is appending an element at the last index. After that, I want to insert another element in array at a particular position. New element is added with the insert() function, but the appended element is deleted.

I am not sure how to save the array that was created with the appended value and then insert a new value to it.

My attempt so far:

```
void insert(int array[], int lastIndex, int index, int elementToAdd);
void append(int array[], int lastIndex, int data);
int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    int n, p;
    int a[size];
    printf("Enter numbers : ");
    input(a, 5);
    printf("You entered these numbers : ");
    display(a, 5);

    printf("\nEnter a new number to append :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    append(a, size, n);

    printf("\nEnter a new number you would like to insert : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the position : ");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    insert(a, size, p, n);
}
void append(int array[], int lastIndex, int data)
{
    array[lastIndex] = data;
    lastIndex++;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
void insert(int array[], int lastIndex, int index, int elementToAdd)
{
    if (index > lastIndex)
    {
        printf("Overbound");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = lastIndex - 1; i >= index - 1; i--)
        {
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
        }
        array[index - 1] = elementToAdd;
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
    }
}
void input(int b[], int N)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
}

void display(int b[], int N)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you create an array of size `5` then add `5` numbers to it. At that point you can't add or insert any more numbers since the array has a fixed size.

Comment: Enter numbers : 1
2
3
4
5
You entered these numbers : 1  2  3  4  5  
Enter a new number to append :6
1 2 3 4 5 6 
Enter a new number you would like to insert : 7
Enter the position : 2
1 7 2 3 4 5 %

Comment: Append is adding a number at the end. And both functions are working fine when i call them separately in a different program.

Comment: See: [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior#Access_out_of_bounds)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because after you append the array with a number, you do not return the new lastIndex to your main function. Therefore you do not use this new lastIndex when calling the `insert` function. You should try something like this:

- Array `arr`: 1 2 3 4
- Append 6 to `arr`: 1 2 3 4 6 (`new`)
- Get the `lastIndex` of `new`
- Use the new `lastIndex` for the insert
- Insert 5 to `new`: 1 2 3 4 5 6

You could return the new `lastIndex` to main, or pass it by reference instead of value.

However, keep in mind that when you create an array of size *n*, it cannot store more numbers than *n*.

EDIT: Maybe you can copy the old array into a bigger one, and then add or insert an element into it. If you dynamically allocate these arrays, you can free the old ones when you don’t need them anymore.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer. The functions are using the original array declared in `main`. There's no need to return it.

Comment: However, you should point out that `lastIndex` is passed by value so that any changes to it in the functions is not reflected in `main`.

Comment: You are totally right! I didn’t even look at it… ouch.